# On the Spivak's proof of the theorem 3-11 (calculus on manifolds)

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In second paragraph of the case 1 within the proof:

1. What is $U$ s.t $A\subset U$ and satisfies in the proof of the case 1 of theorem 3-11.
2. $\psi_i$ is defined on $U_i$ and its support is not compact. Now, How any $\psi_i$ is defined on $U$ s.t $\psi_1+\cdots+\psi_n$  to be well-defind on $U$.
3. Why is $\psi_1+\cdots+\psi_n>0$ on $U$?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For your third question: the bottom of page 63 says that the $\psi_i$ are nonnegative functions, so the only question is why at least one of them is positive at each point. Well, since the interiors of $D$ cover the space, every point is in some $D_i$, and $\psi_i$ is positive on $D_i$, so you're done.

For question 2, since the (finite) sum of the $\psi$s is positive, you can divide by it; the only problem would be if it were zero someplace. So $\phi_i$ is well-defined. If your concern is "what's the value of $\psi_i$ outside of $U_i$?", the answer is that it's defined to be zero out there, so the sum of the $\psi$s is actually defined everywhere.

I don't understand question 1.

Comment: On problem 2-26 $\psi_i$'s are defined on $U_i$ not $U$. What is $U$ s.t all $\psi_i$ are defined on it and $A\subset U$?

Comment: Support of $\psi_i\subset U_i$ is not compact. How Can you extend $\psi_i$ outside of $U_i$ to be zero? In really, why is the sum of the $\psi_i$ actually defined on the $U$? What is $U$? Is $U$ arbitrary?

Comment: Since I don't have problem 1-22 in front of me, I guess I'm unqualified to answer your question in further detail. The symbol $U$ appears to be described in part "4" of the statement of the theorem, however.

Comment: Problem 1-22: If $U$ is open and $C\subset U$ is compact, Show that there is a compact set $D$ such that $C\subset \text{interior}\ D$ and $D\subset U$.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of my thoughts for clarification:

**(1)** Yes, we *can* take $U:= \bigcup \mathring{D_i}$. But more generally we can take the interior of the set of points such that $\sum \psi_i =0$. This contains $\bigcup \mathring{D_i}$ by construction.

**(2)** As $A \subseteq U$, $\phi_i := \frac{ \psi_i}{\sum \psi_i } : U  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is well defined, since $x \in D_i$ for some $i$ making $\psi_i > 0$. Note also that $\phi_i \in C^{\infty}(U)$ by Chain Rule.

**(3)**  It suffices to show $supp (\phi_i) \subseteq U_i$ for each $i$. I believe the text is phrased *weirdly (someone please correct me if I am wrong)* in the start:

> ...$\phi$ is defined on an open set containing $A$...

This seems to imply $\phi$ has domain $U$ open, **so subordinate condition is satisfied as $supp(\phi_i) \subseteq supp(\psi_i)$ and we are done**. I believe we need $\{ \phi_i : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\} $ in $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, as given in this [general definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity), with $X = \mathbb{R}^n$.

**(4)** So our last step is to extend domain. The problem is whether we can define $\phi_i(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [supp(\psi_i) \cap U]^c$. But this does not work!

This is best seen if we only have one open set $U_1$ which covers $A$. We obtain $\phi_1 (x)=1$ on the open set $U = \mathring{D_1}$ that contains $A$. So if we define $\tilde{\phi_1(x)} = 0$ for all $x \notin supp(\psi_1) \cap U = U$ our function is no more continuous (by construction $\phi_1(x) > 0$ on $D_1$).

**(5)** To resolve the problem in highlighted above, $A$ is compact subset of $U$ so we have $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $supp (f) \subseteq U$. By defining

$$ \tilde{\phi_1}(x) = \begin{cases} f \cdot \phi_1(x) & x \in U \\ 
0 & x \notin U \\ 
\end{cases} 
$$
we obtain a $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ function.

Answer (score 0):

I recommand that $U:=\cup_1^n \text{interior}\ D_i$.

Now for compact set  $D_i\subset U$, there exist non negative $C^{\infty} $ function  $\psi_i: U\rightarrow [0,1]$  which is positive on $D_i$ and 0 outside of some closed set ( i.e. $\text{supp}(\psi_i)$) contained in  $U$.